# How do you carry out remote debug when running perl as CGI together with Apache?

Tags: perl, remote-debugging

Seems most are using the traditional way of `print` for debugging purpose, is there anyone that uses remote debug for perl in linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are reasonably straightforward directions here: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Enbugger/lib/Enbugger.pod#From_gdb

Though that presupposes you have a long-running perl process (mod_perl, fastcgi, etc) that wasn't expecting to be run under the debugger.  If you are just using vanilla CGI, you can configure your webserver to run perl -d and set the debugger to remote debugging via its TTY or RemotePort options.  Or go ahead and use Enbugger in your actual perl code as in the directions above (again, setting TTY or RemotePort).

Comment: @ysth,is there a way to debug from perl script level instead of c level?

Comment: yes, that's what that shows; but to debug at the perl script level requires some changes to the optree; Enbugger makes the necessary changes if you use the gdb command shown so that you can start the perl debugger

Comment: @ysth,have you done remote debug in perl level with Enbugger?

Comment: @ysth ,with an IDE such as komodo? I need to do this without any IDE though:(

Comment: No, no IDE.  Just using the RemotePort option and running netcat in a setparate terminal, similar to this: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=629411

Comment: Is it possible when mod_perl is used instead of CGI ?

Comment: How to I trigger the debugger mode with mod_perl?

Comment: Have you gotten it working at all?  It's just the same.  (Well, maybe not with threaded MPMs.)

Answer (score 0):

What sort of debugging? An actual perl debugger or using warn() with tail -f /var/log/apache/error.log?

In the end i would suggest swicting to [Log::Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.33/lib/Log/Log4perl.pm). Unless you need an actual step by step debugger.

You you need an actual debugger, you likely won't want to use Apache in the mix. You can run your cgi from the command line and pass arguments CGI.pm.

Comment: perl script level remote debugging is what I'm after.